# A computational experiment about identities involving the sum of remainders function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, experimental-mathematics

Let $\sigma(m)$ the **sum of divisors function** and $$S(m)=\sum_{k=1}^m\text{m mod k}$$ the **sum of remainders function,** then it is know that for integers $m>1$ 
$$\sigma(m)+S(m)=S(m-1)+2m-1.$$
On the other hand since the sum of divisor functioin is **multiplicative**, on assumption that there exists an **odd perfect number** $n$, we have that $\sigma(\sigma(n))=\sigma(2n)=6n$ and thus $n$ satisfies
$$2n+S(2n)=S(2n-1)-1.$$

> **Fact.** If $l\geq1$ is and odd integer that satisfies $2l+S(2l)=S(2l-1)-1$, then $l$ is perfect and thus an odd perfect number.

The proof is easy since by previous assumption we've $$-\sigma(2l)+4l-1=-2l-1,$$
and the sum of divisors function is multiplicative.

> **Computational fact.** Seem that there are few  even integers $m\geq 1$ satisfying $$2m+S(m)=S(2m-1)-1.$$ The only ones $\leq 10^5=M_0$ are $m=60$ and $336$.

On the other hand if $m=n$ is an odd prefect number, if there is one of them,  we can show also that satisfies each of the following similar conditions about positive integers
$$\sigma(m)=-S(2m)+S(2m-1)-1$$
$$2m=-S(\sigma(m))+S(2m-1)-1,$$
$$2m=-S(2m)+S(\sigma(m)-1)-1$$
or 
$$2m=-S(\sigma(m))+S(\sigma(m)-1)-1.$$

For the three first I don't find integers $1<m<10^5$ satisfying one of them, and the last only $m=24$

> **Question.** **Can you provide us a summary table** with all integers $1<m\leq M$ that you find, for a reasonable upper limit $M$, **using your computer for each of the following conditions**
>   $$f_i(m)=-S(f_i(m))+S(f_i(m)-1)-1,$$
>   where $f_i$ are the arithmetical functions $f_1(m)=\sigma(m)$ and $f_2(m)=2\cdot m$? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If there is a case for which there are a lot of examples of one of the previous conditions, say it, without type all examples. Thanks.

Comment: There was a typo, very thanks much @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1\leq m\leq 10^5$ then formulas (each of them) have no solutions 
$$\sigma(m)=-S(2m)+S(2m-1)-1,$$
$$2m=-S(2m)+S(\sigma(2m)-1)-1,$$
$$2m=-S(\sigma(m))+S(2m-1)-1,$$
$$\sigma(m)=-S(\sigma(m))+S(2m-1)-1$$
or
$$\sigma(m)=-S(2m)+S(\sigma(m)-1)-1$$
The following have solutions (only in the segment of integers $1\leq m\leq 10^5$ )
$$2m=-S(2m)+S(2m-1)-1,\text{has solutions }60\text{ and }336,$$
$$2m=-S(\sigma(m))+S(\sigma(m)-1)-1,\text{has solutions }24\text{ and }87402,$$
$$\sigma(m)=-S(\sigma(m))+S(\sigma(m)-1)-1$$
$$\text{has solutions }54,56,87, 95, 276, 308, 429, 446, 455, 501, 581\text{ and }611.$$

Comment: If you can improve my computations please add an answer this week. Also I would like to do a comparision of the last identity with **A066961**, in **https://oeis.org**, for example 427 isn't in my last sequence.